# Can you extend the val() function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, extend

Is there a way to extend the val() function in jQuery.

Basically, what I want to do is set a class variable if there is content being dynamically entered into an input.

Whick normally would be something like

```
var thisVal = 'Hello World';    
$('#myInput').val(thisVal).addClass('dark');
```

It would just be nice to tell the val() function to always add the class 'dark' to an input if there is a value, and to remove it if it is empty.

Possible?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$.fn.xval = function () {
    return this.toggleClass(arguments.length).val.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/v9YFu/

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do this:

```
var oldVal = $.fn.val;
$.fn.val = function(value) {
    $(this).addClass("dark");
    return oldVal.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

But I'd strongly discourage you to use it because setting an element's value has nothing to do with setting CSS properties. `val` sets values, and that's it. What you could do is this:

```
$("#someInput").change(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("dark");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("dark");
    }
});
```

The function you pass to change will be called, whenever the value is changed - programmatically or by the user ([see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/)). This way the code gets much more readable and comprehensible, what makes it easier to debug too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.darkVal = function (value) { return this.addClass('dark').val(value); };
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by other answers, you *can* extend (overwrite) the val() function but it's not good practice to hardcode unrelated behaviour into it.

However, I find that a handy way of triggering something when the value is changed programatically is to overwrite the val() function and trigger the change event of your element - BUT ONLY IF SPECIFIED by that element.

You can define that request by adding a data attribute (or class etc.) to your element like so:

```html
<!-- Add the data-trigger-change attribute -->
<input data-trigger-change class="dark-when-changed" name="test" value="123">
```

Then, your new val function can check for that attribute.

```js
const fnVal = $.fn.val;

$.fn.val = function(value) {
 // check if the value is actually changing
 let changed = typeof value!=='undefined' && typeof $(this)[0] !=='undefined' && value !== $(this)[0].value;
 // change the value by the standard method
 let $return = fnVal.apply(this, arguments);
 // if this element wants to trigger the change method (and it has actually changed)
 if(changed && $(this).is('[data-trigger-change]')) {
  // trigger the change method
  $(this).trigger("change");
  // return the original response
  return $return;
 }
 // return the original response without doing anything else
 return $return;
};
```

...and then you can write a change handler to do whatever you like:

```js
$(document).on('change','input.dark-when-changed',function(){
  $(this).addClass('dark');
});
```

**WARNING!** Doing this can result in an infinite loop if you change the value in your change handler using val(), obviously. If you really needed to, you could avoid that by using $('input.dark-when-changed')[0].value = 'blah';